# how to restore application panel in opensuse 12.1 kde 4?

Tags: opensuse, kde-4

I have accidentally removed desktop panel that shows applications currently running on. I'm noob on  and I can't find a way how to restore it back. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I have found a solution (not desired one but it works...):

[How do I go about restoring default the openSUSE 11.3 KDE 4 desktop.](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/457630-how-do-i-go-about-restoring-default-opensuse-11-3-kde-4-desktop.html)